# uWSGI error hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I have deployed a flask web application using uWSGI and NGINX as the reverse proxy. The application response time is about 9ms on average but after a batch of requests my workers crashed and I got this log on my uWSGI log:

```
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 24488] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 4059] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 46764] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 9951] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 9449] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 51355] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 39565] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 63142] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 7861] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 10165] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 10917] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
[uwsgi-http key: backend client_addr: 172.17.0.1 client_port: 20392] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
```

**The uWSGI config:**

```
[uwsgi]
http = 0.0.0.0:7000
wsgi-file = app.py
callable = app
processes = 5
lazy = true
lazy-apps = true
buffer-size = 16384
logto = /root/logs/data-gathering.log
```

**Env:**

```
uWSGI==2.0.17
Flask==0.12.2
```

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1831

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with uWSGI native HTTP server. With the following configuration:

```
https = :8443,app.crt,app.key,HIGH,!ca.crt
http-workers = 2
http-buffer-size = 32768

; applications
mount = /=/app.py
mount = /asq=/asq.py

; process managment
master = true
vacuum = true
single-interpreter = true
pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi.pid
enable-threads = true
cpu-affinity = 1
processes = 4
threads = 2
offload-threads = 1

close-on-exec = true
buffer-size = 32768
```

I always got:

```
[uwsgi-http key: 192.168.1.200:8443 client_addr: 192.168.1.200 client_port: 20179] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
```

In my case I was performing **POST** requests and not consuming the body. So after adding `post-buffering = 1` to the configuration everything just started to work fine. Same result without the flag and just reading the **POST** data.

And from uWSGI's "Things to know":

> If an HTTP request has a body (like a POST request generated by a
>   form), you have to read (consume) it in your application. If you do
>   not do this, the communication socket with your webserver may be
>   clobbered. If you are lazy you can use the post-buffering option that
>   will automatically read data for you. For Rack applications this is
>   automatically enabled.